# How to set dynamic url in pluoplad-angular-directive?

Tags: angularjs, plupload

I am trying to use `plupload-angular-directive` in my Angular SPA. The problem is, the upload URL is not a constant and is generated on the server side every time I need to upload something.

So, as mentioned in the [docs](http://sahusoftcom.github.io/plupload-angular-directive/) I have used the pl-url directive to set the URL on the front-end like this:

```
<button pl-upload=""
            pl-auto-upload="true"
            pl-files-model="multiFiles"
            pl-url="{{imgActionUrl}}"
            pl-progress-model="percent">Upload Images</button>
```

where, the `imgActionUrl` is fetched by my Angular controller and assigned to the `$scope`.

Debugging the application clearly showed that the URL is being properly set but even then, when the upload actually happens, it makes a `POST` to `/upload.php` rather than to the address mentioned in the directive.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging around, I posted an issue on the github page of the project:

https://github.com/sahusoftcom/plupload-angular-directive/issues/43

But it seems nobody is maintaining this repository and the owner redirected me to another library, jQuery-File-Upload.